# Java Socket - POP3 - check if new mail

Tags: java, sockets, pop3

So I want to check every 3 second if I have new mail. On my mailbox I have now 9 mails so here is the result of my program:

```
Test
1 0a061c60b94e11e6
Test
2 0ab96602b94e11e6
Test
3 8c644458b96211e6
Test
4 1f057024b96611e6
Test
5 b309f824b96611e6
Test
6 c9018332b96611e6
Test
7 1c614f11b96811e6
Test
8 a7b0a6d7b96a11e6
Test
9 0c669444b97d11e6
Test
.
Test
```

And when I send new mail, I don't get any message. I should get:

```
10 some_letters_and_numbers
```

But nothing happens. I even don't see "Test" every 3 seconds. It just stop. Here is my code:

```
public void makeConnection(ConfigData configData) throws IOException {
    socket = new Socket(configData.getServerAddress(), configData.getPort());
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
    String response = reader.readLine();
    sendCommand("USER " + configData.getUsername());
    sendCommand("PASS " + configData.getPassword());
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(mailRunnable, 0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
protected String sendCommand(String command) throws IOException {
    writer.write(command + "\n");
    writer.flush();
    String response = reader.readLine();
    return response;
}
Runnable mailRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Test");
            String response = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println(response);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Somebody have maybe any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: One thing you're doing wrong is not using JavaMail, and another is sending the wrong line terminator.

Comment: I doubt that the code you show matches the output. Based on the output you somewhere send a LIST command but this is not shown in your code.

Comment: I can't use JavaMail and LIST. I have to use only this commands: USER, PASS, UIDL, QUIT. It's my task from studies and I have to use just sockets, without any ready things like JavaMail.